# SKProductsRequest over server?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, skproduct

I have an app where I get a list of product IDs from the server, which I then send to Apple to get a list of SKProducts, which I then send back to the server to get html, which I put all together to make a webview with the products.

This is very complicated- is there a way for the server to communicate with Apple directly without having to do all the back and forth?

Answer (score 0):

No. Your app has to make a request to the iTunes store directly from the device it is running on (to ensure correct handling of the user's iTunes account, including appropriate prices for the region, etc.).

It sounds like your app-server communication structure is not the most efficient; it'd be easier if you generated the storefront web view **inside your app, locally on the device** (or even found a better, native way of displaying the information, such as a `UITableView` or `UICollectionView`), instead of sending the IDs to the server. This would eliminate a lot of the back-and-forth resulting from you doing this in a way that was certainly not intended.